how to limit code verification email Spaming in Azure B2C
I've been trying to see how can I limit the number of codes being send to an email during the signup/reset password.
I couldn't find a simple solution from Azure for that.
What I could find is:
configuring AFD (azure front door) limit for API calls but that's also kind of complicated and doesn't work 100%.
is there any better solution? there has to be something.
thanks.

Have you tried OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider's NumCodeGenerationAttempts? This is still not the ideal solution as the user can start a new session and still continue to spam
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile#protocol

Thanks a lot ! this is what i was looking for
